# Granting Read access to Category for specific Groups using PowerShell Scripts

Tags: 2013-sp1, powershell, keyword

For reference please see the script running for updating the category with specific groups and granting read permission:-

```
$groupI  = (Get-TridionGroup -GroupName "Group I").Id
$groupIRead = @{}
$groupIRead.Add($groupI, "Read")
Update-TridionCategory -WebdavUrl "webdav/C010 Dummy Schemas/Dummy" -Permissions $groupIRead -Verbose 


$groupII = (Get-TridionGroup -GroupName "Group II").Id
$groupIIRead = @{}
$groupIIRead.Add($groupII, "Read")
Update-TridionCategory -WebdavUrl "webdav/C010 Dummy Schemas/Dummy" -Permissions  $groupIIRead -Verbose
```

After running the above script category is updating with only GroupII whichever group is executed at the last only with that group category is getting updated.

Comment: It looks like you are using Peter Kjaer's Tridion powershell module for Get-TridionGroup. Or perhaps this is your own function. Have you written Update-TridionCategory yourself? Please add the necessary information to your question.

Comment: You might find this blog post interesting. https://blog.indivirtual.nl/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overwriting your permissions. use one update statement. add both groups to your hashtable. not tested, but I think this will work:

```
$groupI  = (Get-TridionGroup -GroupName "Group I").Id
$groupRead = @{}
$groupRead.Add($groupI, "Read")

$groupII = (Get-TridionGroup -GroupName "Group II").Id
$groupRead.Add($groupII, "Read")
Update-TridionCategory -WebdavUrl "webdav/C010 Dummy Schemas/Dummy" -Permissions  $groupRead -Verbose
```

Comment: I don't have the update-tridioncategory method. can you post the source for that?

Comment: One more thing I missed out to mention whatever scripts you told to try first group is updating the category for 2nd group facing error preparing to add: tcm:0-000-40000 with permission:Read  Added tcm:0-000-40000-to ACL preparing to add:tcm:0-001-40002 with permission:Read Update-TridionCategory:Method invocation failed because[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.AccessControlEntryData] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.At line:1 char:2+ Update-TridionCategory -WebdavUrl "webdav/DummySchemas/Dummy CategoryInfo  :InvalidOperation:(op_Addition:String)[Update-TridionCategory]

Comment: I'm asking for the powershell source code for update-tridioncategory. I don't have that in my code base. it look like need a different approach for adding multiple groups.

Comment: It does indeed look like you are overwriting the permissions, but it's impossible to tell without seeing Update-TridionCategory.